# Select Iframe inside other tags on Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, iframe, xpath

Good day everyone.

First, here is a TL;DR version:

I need to select an element inside an iframe which is also inside many other HTML tags.

Now, the actual problem:

Today I`m trying to solve a little problem I have at work. Every day I need to perform a time-consuming task of filling a form with some information. The thing is that every form must be completed in the exactly same way and I have to do this on an individual web page. I learned about Selenium a few months back and tried to use it on the site so that I could automate this process.

The thing is that I ran into a problem. Apparently, Selenium IDE doesn't recognize iframes. I tried to export the code to Python 2.7 and edit it according to some stack overflow solutions I`ve found, but apparently, nothing works, probably because I'm new to this kind of thing.

The iframe is located inside of a bunch of other HTML tags( like table, spam, body, etc.i) soI have no idea on how to get to it.

Below is part of the webpage's code that contains the iframe and just after it is the test that I tried to automate using Python 2.7. Have in mind that I'm completely new to python and I've only used Selenium IDE once so far.

HTML code simplified by section:

```
<table class="dialog tabbed " id="tabDialog_6" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

<tbody>


##A bunch of tables, spam, and bodies above.


<iframe id="descrpt_ifr" src='javascript:""' frameborder="0" style="width: 100%; height: 126px;" tabindex="78">

</iframe>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="mceLast"><td class="mceStatusbar mceFirst mceLast">
<div id="descrpt_path_row">&nbsp;<a href="#" accesskey="x">
</a>
</div>
<a id="descrpt_resize" href="javascript:;" onclick="return false;" class="mceResize">
</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</span>
<script>var WYSIWYGdisplayed = Boolean(window.tinyMCE != null);
</script>&nbsp;<table style="vertical-align: text-bottom; display: inline;" width="1%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td nowrap="" style="border: none;">
<a id="oylyLink" title="Spell Check" class="button" href="javascript: void spellCheck(document.regform.LADD)" tabindex="79" onfocus="document.getElementById('oyly').onmouseover();" onblur="document.getElementById('oyly').onmouseout();">
<div id="oyly" class="button_off" onmousedown="mousedownButton('oyly');" onmouseup="highlightButton(false, 'oyly');" onmouseover="highlightButton(true, 'oyly');" onmouseout="highlightButton(false, 'oyly');" style="">
<img src="/MRimg/spell_check.png" alt="Spell Check" border="0" align="absmiddle" id="oyly_image">
</div>
</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="descriptionSectionHeader">Complete Description (PUBLIC)
</div>

<div class="indented"><iframe src="/tmp/alldesc_61121857.html" name="ALL_DESCS" width="702" height="170" scrolling="yes" wrap="hard"></iframe></div>   
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Entire html code of the page:

```
<table class="dialog tabbed " id="tabDialog_6" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <script language="javascript"> tabIDs['Description'] = "tabDialog_6"; </script> 
    <tbody><tr>
       <td class="dialogMainContent">
    <div id="newDesc" class="descriptionSectionHeader"><label id="LADD_label" for="descrpt" class="">Append New Description (PUBLIC)<span class="asteriskHolder">*</span></label></div><div class="indented">
                    <script language="JavaScript">

            function combineFields () {
                  var flds = new Array();
                  var res = new Array();
                  for (var i=0; i< flds.length; i++) {
                     var fld = document.regform.elements[flds[i]];
                     if (fld != null)
                     {
                     if (fld.type == 'select-one' && fld.selectedIndex>=0 && fld.options[fld.selectedIndex].value) {
                        res.push (fld.name+'='+fld.options[fld.selectedIndex].value);
                     } else if (fld.type == 'text'  && fld.value) {
                        res.push (fld.name+'='+fld.value);
                     } else if (fld.type == 'select-multiple' && fld.selectedIndex>=0) {
                        var sel = new Array();
                        for (var j=0; j< fld.options.length; j++) {
                            if (fld.options[j].selected && fld.options[j].value) {
                                sel.push(fld.options[j].value);
                            }
                        }
                        if (sel.length> 0){res.push (fld.name+'~'+sel.join('|'));}
                     } else if (fld.type == 'checkbox' && fld.checked) {
                           res.push (fld.name+'='+fld.value);
                     } else if (fld.type == 'textarea' && fld.value) {
                           res.push (fld.name+'~'+fld.value);
                     }
                   }
                   }
                   var ret = encodeURIComponent(res.join(','));
                   ret = '&SOLFILTR=' + (ret || "__nothing__");
                   return ret;
           }


                     function searchsolutions() {
                       var height = 530;
                       var width = 660;
                       var str = combineFields();

                       window.open('/MRcgi/MRshowsolutions_page.pl?USER=UserPROJECTID=2&MRP=5pIpUWj0&REGPAGE=0&SELECTSOLUTION=1&SESS_ID=9c91e9288993272a387fbe9f9f7c0fac&SAVEDNAME=SOL'+str, 'solsearch', 'top=176,left=133,width=' + width + ',height=' + height + ',status=yes,toolbar=no,directories=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');
                    }
                    </script>
                <table class="inlineDialogHeading indented">
    <tbody><tr>
    <td><table style="vertical-align: text-bottom; display: inline;" width="1%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tbody><tr><td nowrap="" style="border: none;"><a id="searchKBButtonLink" title="Search Knowledge Base" class="button" href="javascript:searchsolutions();" tabindex="77" onfocus="document.getElementById('searchKBButton').onmouseover();" onblur="document.getElementById('searchKBButton').onmouseout();"><div id="searchKBButton" class="button_off" onmousedown="mousedownButton('searchKBButton');" onmouseup="highlightButton(false, 'searchKBButton');" onmouseover="highlightButton(true, 'searchKBButton');" onmouseout="highlightButton(false, 'searchKBButton');" style=""><img src="/MRimg/knowledge_base.png" alt="Search Knowledge Base" border="0" align="absmiddle" id="searchKBButton_image"> <span id="searchKBButton_textSpan" style=" height: 18px; cursor: pointer;">Search Knowledge Base</span></div></a></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr>
    </tbody></table>
    <textarea name="LADD" title="Description (PUBLIC)" cols="85" id="descrpt" tabindex="-1" onkeypress="addAutoSpell(document.regform.LADD)" style="height: 170px; width: 702px; display: none;" class="wysiwyg"></textarea><span id="descrpt_parent" class="mceEditor defaultSkin"><table id="descrpt_tbl" class="mceLayout" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 702px; height: 170px;"><tbody><tr class="mceFirst"><td class="mceToolbar mceLeft mceFirst mceLast"><a href="#" accesskey="q" title="Jump to tool buttons - Alt+Q, Jump to editor - Alt-Z, Jump to element path - Alt-X"><!-- IE --></a><table id="descrpt_toolbar1" class="mceToolbar mceToolbarRow1 Enabled" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align=""><tbody><tr><td class="mceToolbarStart mceToolbarStartButton mceFirst"><span><!-- IE --></span></td><td><a id="descrpt_newdocument" href="javascript:;" class="mceButton mceButtonEnabled mce_newdocument" onmousedown="return false;" onclick="return false;" title="New document"><span class="mceIcon mce_newdocument"></span></a></td><td><span class="mceSeparator"></span></td><td><a id="descrpt_cut" href="javascript:;" class="mceButton mceButtonEnabled mce_cut" onmousedown="return false;" onclick="return false;" title="Cut"><span class="mceIcon mce_cut"></span></a></td><td><a id="descrpt_copy" href="javascript:;" class="mceButton mceButtonEnabled mce_copy" onmousedown="return false;" onclick="return false;" title="Copy"><span class="mceIcon mce_copy"></span></a></td><td><a id="descrpt_paste" href="javascript:;" class="mceButton mceButtonEnabled mce_paste" onmousedown="return false;" onclick="return false;" title="Paste"><span class="mceIcon mce_paste"></span></a></td><td><a id="descrpt_undo" href="javascript:;" class="mceButton mce_undo mceButtonEnabled" onmousedown="return false;" onclick="return false;" title="Undo (Ctrl+Z)"><span class="mceIcon mce_undo"></span></a></td><td><a id="descrpt_redo" href="javascript:;" class="mceButton mce_redo mceButtonDisabled" onmousedown="return false;" onclick="return false;" title="Redo (Ctrl+Y)"><span class="mceIcon mce_redo"></span></a></td><td><span class="mceSeparator"></span></td><td><table id="descrpt_fontselect" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mceListBox mceListBoxEnabled mce_fontselect"><tbody><tr><td class="mceFirst"><a id="descrpt_fontselect_text" href="javascript:;" class="mceText mceTitle" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="return false;">Font family</a></td><td class="mceLast"><a id="descrpt_fontselect_open" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:;" class="mceOpen" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="return false;"><span></span></a></td></tr></tbody></table></td><td><table id="descrpt_fontsizeselect" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mceListBox mceListBoxEnabled mce_fontsizeselect"><tbody><tr><td class="mceFirst"><a id="descrpt_fontsizeselect_text" href="javascript:;" class="mceText mceTitle" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="return false;">Font size</a></td><td class="mceLast"><a id="descrpt_fontsizeselect_open" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:;" class="mceOpen" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="return false;"><span></span></a></td></tr></tbody></table></td><td><span class="mceSeparator"></span></td><td><table id="descrpt_forecolor" class="mceSplitButton mceSplitButtonEnabled mce_forecolor" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" onmousedown="return false;" title="Select text color"><tbody><tr><td class="mceFirst"><a id="descrpt_forecolor_action" href="javascript:;" class="mceAction mce_forecolor" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="return false;" title="Select text color"><span class="mceAction mce_forecolor"></span><div id="descrpt_forecolor_preview" class="mceColorPreview" style="background-color: rgb(136, 136, 136);"></div></a></td><td class="mceLast"><a id="descrpt_forecolor_open" href="javascript:;" class="mceOpen mce_forecolor" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="return false;" title="Select text color"><span class="mceOpen mce_forecolor"></span></a></td></tr></tbody></table></td><td><table id="descrpt_backcolor" class="mceSplitButton mceSplitButtonEnabled mce_backcolor" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" onmousedown="return false;" title="Select background color"><tbody><tr><td class="mceFirst"><a id="descrpt_backcolor_action" href="javascript:;" class="mceAction mce_backcolor" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="return false;" title="Select background color"><span class="mceAction mce_backcolor"></span><div id="descrpt_backcolor_preview" class="mceColorPreview" style="background-color: rgb(136, 136, 136);"></div></a></td><td class="mceLast"><a id="descrpt_backcolor_open" href="javascript:;" class="mceOpen mce_backcolor" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="return false;" title="Select background color"><span class="mceOpen mce_backcolor"></span></a></td></tr></tbody></table></td><td><span class="mceSeparator"></span></td><td><a id="descrpt_bold" href="javascript:;" class="mceButton mceButtonEnabled mce_bold" onmousedown="return false;" onclick="return false;" title="Bold (Ctrl+B)"><span class="mceIcon mce_bold"></span></a></td><td><a id="descrpt_italic" href="javascript:;" class="mceButton mceButtonEnabled mce_italic" onmousedown="return false;" onclick="return false;" title="Italic (Ctrl+I)"><span class="mceIcon mce_italic"></span></a></td><td><a id="descrpt_underline" href="javascript:;" class="mceButton mceButtonEnabled mce_underline" onmousedown="return false;" onclick="return false;" title="Underline (Ctrl+U)"><span class="mceIcon mce_underline"></span></a></td><td><span class="mceSeparator"></span></td><td><a id="descrpt_justifyleft" href="javascript:;" class="mceButton mceButtonEnabled mce_justifyleft" onmousedown="return false;" onclick="return false;" title="Align left"><span class="mceIcon mce_justifyleft"></span></a></td><td><a id="descrpt_justifycenter" href="javascript:;" class="mceButton mceButtonEnabled mce_justifycenter" onmousedown="return false;" onclick="return false;" title="Align center"><span class="mceIcon mce_justifycenter"></span></a></td><td><a id="descrpt_justifyright" href="javascript:;" class="mceButton mceButtonEnabled mce_justifyright" onmousedown="return false;" onclick="return false;" title="Align right"><span class="mceIcon mce_justifyright"></span></a></td><td><a id="descrpt_justifyfull" href="javascript:;" class="mceButton mceButtonEnabled mce_justifyfull" onmousedown="return false;" onclick="return false;" title="Align full"><span class="mceIcon mce_justifyfull"></span></a></td><td><span class="mceSeparator"></span></td><td><a id="descrpt_bullist" href="javascript:;" class="mceButton mceButtonEnabled mce_bullist" onmousedown="return false;" onclick="return false;" title="Unordered list"><span class="mceIcon mce_bullist"></span></a></td><td><a id="descrpt_numlist" href="javascript:;" class="mceButton mceButtonEnabled mce_numlist" onmousedown="return false;" onclick="return false;" title="Ordered list"><span class="mceIcon mce_numlist"></span></a></td><td><span class="mceSeparator"></span></td><td><a id="descrpt_outdent" href="javascript:;" class="mceButton mce_outdent mceButtonDisabled" onmousedown="return false;" onclick="return false;" title="Outdent"><span class="mceIcon mce_outdent"></span></a></td><td><a id="descrpt_indent" href="javascript:;" class="mceButton mceButtonEnabled mce_indent" onmousedown="return false;" onclick="return false;" title="Indent"><span class="mceIcon mce_indent"></span></a></td><td><span class="mceSeparator"></span></td><td><a id="descrpt_table" href="javascript:;" class="mceButton mceButtonEnabled mce_table" onmousedown="return false;" onclick="return false;" title="Inserts a new table"><span class="mceIcon mce_table"></span></a></td><td><a id="descrpt_hr" href="javascript:;" class="mceButton mceButtonEnabled mce_hr" onmousedown="return false;" onclick="return false;" title="Insert horizontal ruler"><span class="mceIcon mce_hr"></span></a></td><td><a id="descrpt_charmap" href="javascript:;" class="mceButton mceButtonEnabled mce_charmap" onmousedown="return false;" onclick="return false;" title="Insert custom character"><span class="mceIcon mce_charmap"></span></a></td><td><a id="descrpt_link" href="javascript:;" class="mceButton mce_link mceButtonEnabled" onmousedown="return false;" onclick="return false;" title="Insert/edit link"><span class="mceIcon mce_link"></span></a></td><td><a id="descrpt_image" href="javascript:;" class="mceButton mceButtonEnabled mce_image" onmousedown="return false;" onclick="return false;" title="Insert/edit image"><span class="mceIcon mce_image"></span></a></td><td class="mceToolbarEnd mceToolbarEndButton mceLast"><span><!-- IE --></span></td></tr></tbody></table><a href="#" accesskey="z" title="Jump to tool buttons - Alt+Q, Jump to editor - Alt-Z, Jump to element path - Alt-X" onfocus="tinyMCE.getInstanceById('descrpt').focus();"><!-- IE --></a></td></tr><tr><td class="mceIframeContainer mceFirst mceLast">


##THE IFRAME IS RIGHT IN THIS SECTION



<iframe id="descrpt_ifr" src='javascript:""' frameborder="0" style="width: 100%; height: 126px;" tabindex="78">

</iframe>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="mceLast"><td class="mceStatusbar mceFirst mceLast">
<div id="descrpt_path_row">&nbsp;<a href="#" accesskey="x">
</a>
</div>
<a id="descrpt_resize" href="javascript:;" onclick="return false;" class="mceResize">
</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</span>
<script>var WYSIWYGdisplayed = Boolean(window.tinyMCE != null);
</script>&nbsp;<table style="vertical-align: text-bottom; display: inline;" width="1%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td nowrap="" style="border: none;">
<a id="oylyLink" title="Spell Check" class="button" href="javascript: void spellCheck(document.regform.LADD)" tabindex="79" onfocus="document.getElementById('oyly').onmouseover();" onblur="document.getElementById('oyly').onmouseout();">
<div id="oyly" class="button_off" onmousedown="mousedownButton('oyly');" onmouseup="highlightButton(false, 'oyly');" onmouseover="highlightButton(true, 'oyly');" onmouseout="highlightButton(false, 'oyly');" style="">
<img src="/MRimg/spell_check.png" alt="Spell Check" border="0" align="absmiddle" id="oyly_image">
</div>
</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="descriptionSectionHeader">Complete Description (PUBLIC)
</div>

<div class="indented"><iframe src="/tmp/alldesc_61121857.html" name="ALL_DESCS" width="702" height="170" scrolling="yes" wrap="hard"></iframe></div>   
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

My Selenium IDE code exported to python.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import unittest, time, re

class CasoDeTesteStiMEmPython(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "THE WEBPAGE I NEED TO FILL THE FORM"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_caso_de_teste_sti_m_em_python(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/MRcgi/MRhomepage.pl?USER=yferreir&PROJECTID=3&MRP=bmKXVpJkDK&OPTION=none&WRITECACHE=1&FIRST_TIME_IN_FP=1&FIRST_TIME_IN_PROJ=1&REMEMBER_SCREEN=1&")
        driver.find_element_by_id("SEARCHS").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("SEARCHS").send_keys("404905")
        driver.find_element_by_id("splitbutton1-button").click()
        # ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [waitForPopUp | details404905 | 100000]]
        # ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectWindow | name=details404905 | ]]
        driver.find_element_by_id("editButton_image").click()
        Select(driver.find_element_by_id("status")).select_by_visible_text("Under Investigation")
         ##RIGHT HERE IS WHERE I NEED TO SELECT THE IFRAME
         ##THE FOLLOWING PARTS OF THE CODE WITH ## ARE FROM A STACKOVERFLOW SOLUTION I TRIED


        ## Give time for iframe to load ##
        time.sleep(3)
        ## You have to switch to the iframe like so: ##
        driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("descrpt_ifr"))
        ## Insert text via xpath ##
        elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="tinymce"]/p")
        elem.send_keys("WHAT I NEED TO WRITE IN THE ELEMENT INSIDE THE IFRAME")
        ## Switch back to the "default content" (that is, out of the iframes) ##
        driver.switch_to_default_content()
        # ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectWindow | name=details404905 | ]]
        driver.find_element_by_id("goButton_textSpan").click()
        # ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectWindow | null | ]]
        driver.find_element_by_id("SEARCHS").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("SEARCHS").send_keys("404905")
        driver.find_element_by_id("splitbutton1-button").click()
        # ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [waitForPopUp | details404905 | 100000]]
        # ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectWindow | name=details404905 | ]]
        driver.find_element_by_id("editButton_textSpan").click()
        Select(driver.find_element_by_id("status")).select_by_visible_text("Solved")
        driver.find_element_by_id("tab_1").click()
        Select(driver.find_element_by_id("userfield22")).select_by_visible_text("Administration")
        driver.find_element_by_id("userfield24").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("userfield24").send_keys("Cancelamento realizado com sucesso.")
        driver.find_element_by_id("goButton_textSpan").click()

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException as e: return False
        return True

    def is_alert_present(self):
        try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        except NoAlertPresentException as e: return False
        return True

    def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
        try:
            alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
            alert_text = alert.text
            if self.accept_next_alert:
                alert.accept()
            else:
                alert.dismiss()
            return alert_text
        finally: self.accept_next_alert = True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I've tryed using the iframe's ID "descrpt_ifr" and the folloing Xpaths:

Iframe Xpath: //*[@id="descrpt_ifr"].

Element inside Iframe i want to use Xpath: //*[@id="tinymce"]/p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the line of code used to switch to the iframe is causing the error

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("descrpt_ifr"))
```

'descrpt_ifr' is not a tag name. Change it to

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_id("descrpt_ifr"))
```

Or use xpath to identify the iframe in case there are multiple matching nodes for the id.

Comment: Ill try this today.
Another question, Ive tried to execute the test just just to see what i have working so far but for some reason it doesnt open the page, it just opens the browser. Any idea of why this happens?

Comment: Could be related to Firefox. Was it recently upgraded to version 48? For now you can downgrade Firefox to get them working again or use a different browser (chrome?). Have a look at this link for more info: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2559

Comment: Well apparently i have many more problems with the page and the script that i thought i would. I`m sure your answer is correct but i don`t think it is the only solution ill need. Thanks anyway buddy.